# unlock the usb port of Dell Laptop(WindowXP)

Tags: windows, usb, hacking

I am using a laptop, Dell630, Window XP. As my company policy, the computer is running a daemon program to lock the USB port. the USB device  can only be read, can not be write. So I want to make it also write able. Any idea of how to make it the USB writeable?

thanks

Answer (score 6):

No. No. No.

Company policy is company policy whether you like it or not. If you **need** it, talk to your manager and go through the official channels.

Comment: +1. The questioner needs to ask him-/her-self if the potential disciplinary action is worth being able to write to a USB device from that machine for.